# Script editor opening folder and questioning to delete it

Tags: macos, applescript, finder

I want the program to open a folder and then display a text to delete this folder, but I can't get it working. Any help is appreciated.

```
    on opening folder theResponse
    tell application "Finder"
    set theName to name of theResponse
    activate
    display alert "Attention!" message "The folder" & theName & " was opened."
    set question to display dialog "Do you want to delete this folder?" buttons {"No", "Yes"} default button "No"
    set answer to button returned of question
    if answer is equal to "Yes" then
    set sourceFolder to theName
    move sourceFolder to the trash
        end tell
    end opening folder
```

Answer (score 0):

`theName` is the folder name – a string – for example `Pictures` or `Movies`. You need the reference to the folder (Finder specifier or alias) which is `theResponse`

Delete

```
set sourceFolder to theName
```

and change

```
move theResponse to the trash
```